what connotation does the word 'spirit' in "that child's got too much spirit for a girl of her circumstance" have?
In the movie "Notebook", there is a line "that child's got too much spirit for a girl of her circumstance"
as shown below.
I think it means
"7: a lively or brisk quality in a person or a person's actions" as defined in Merriam-webster dictionary or energy or enthusiasm.
What connotation does this word 'spirit' convey as opposed to 'energy' or 'enthusiasm'?  Why would you use the word 'spirit' here? Is that because it goes well with the word 'circumstance'?
Thank you.


Yes, as Merriam-Webster says, and also Cambridge is good: enthusiasm, energy, or courage, Collins:  the liveliness and energy that someone shows in what they do.  Oxford: Courage; boldness, assertiveness, mettle. I would use it because it is the right word to use, and is suited to the period of the film.

For me, from among the definitions @MichaelHarvey provides, Oxford’s is easily the most apt: “Courage; boldness, assertiveness, mettle.”

If she is from "high society" and from the 1940s, the implication of "too much spirit" could well be that she is not as demure, reserved, and "ladylike" as she is expected to be.

Please note: the film is called "The Notebook".

@TimR -  that was my first thought as well. The attitude you describe lasted in the British upper classes until the 1960s (or later in the case of the royal family). Such a person might be labelled as 'pert'.

In the US, we call other things "pert".

@TimR - yes, we have that as well. In fact, aged roughly 11 onwards, I got that meaning of 'pert' from Mickey Spillane (those covers!), etc, and the 'cheeky, forward of manner' meaning later.

Merriam-Webster's definition 9: : 'a mental disposition characterized by firmness or assertiveness.'

Thank you all for the comments.

This character means that the girl is too bold or assertive - perhaps that she has too many opinions or ambition, and that it will harm her. The phrase "for a girl of her circumstance" implies that the child in question is poor or that her family doesn't have a lot of resources or opportunities.
The characters discussing the child are saying that her life would be easier (or more expected) if she was duller or if she didn't have so many hopes and dreams and opinions, since the world does not expect those things of a child in her situation.

@MariosAthanasiou are you advertising for your answer? Why?? If it's a good answer, people will probably upvote it and you will gain reputation naturally. If you get feedback on it, take that feedback, use it, and answer more questions. The goal on this site is to help other people grow English skills, not to get points.
